# Plotting multiple curves every end of a sequence of a third different column from 2 plotted columns

Tags: gnuplot

I can't figure how to plot multiple curves which start and ends after every sequence. My sequences repeats itself for "N" times (many) from 1 to 5. I want to plot column2 versus column3 and have a different curve each time column1 (using it as ternary operator) goes from 1 to 5.

In the eample it should come out a graph with 2 curves. The sequence is a variable itself it's not a constant number of points.

```
for example:

     column1         column2          column3
1      1                2                4
2      1                3                6
3      1                5                7
4      1                9                0
5      2                5                7
6      2                8                9
7      3                9                6
8      4                4                3
9      4                2                4 
10     4                6                9
11     4                0                0
12     5                7                0 
13     5                6                8
14     1                5                2
15     2                3                5
16     3                6                7
17     4                8                3
18     4                2                1
19     4                2                6
20     5                8                9
```

Linepoints would be the best, but with points it also very good. The colour is not important, there is no need to have a key.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your (non)working script and the result.

Comment: @theozh in a rush of anger I cancelled the code, and tried to solve the problem with python (pandas) using an old question that I made here in stackoverflow. Wich theoretically works but I have to go from .xlsx to .txt and change other factors and I was wondering if I could  do it directly with gnuplot.

Comment: ok, anger is not good. Simply, describe exactly what you have, what you want and what you've tried. Please always include some minimized (but not incomplete, like you did now) example data. What plotting style do you want, `with lines` or `with points` or something else...? What colors do you want? Please include such details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few details unclear and missing from your description, so I'll make assumptions.

- in principle, you could plot your split data `every ::0::12` and `every ::13::19` (line index is zero-based), but I assume the number of lines will be variable and different for each datafile.
- you want to plot column2 and column3 versus column1 (but maybe you want to plot column2 versus column3)? I assume the former.
- you want to plot `with points`. In contrast, `with lines` will get more complicated because your data doesn't contain breaks after column1 goes from `5` back to `1`.
- you did not specify if your column1 increases from `1` to `5` only twice or maybe `N` times?

Generally, often you can adapt your data, so that the plot commands will be easier or in case you cannot or don't want to change the original data, the plotting commands might get a bit more complicated.

Ok, as a starting point to get any further check the following example (with some completed test data):

**Script:**

```
### break data into subsets
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1   11.0   21.0
1   11.3   21.3
1   11.6   21.6
1   11.9   21.9
2   12.0   22.0
2   12.5   22.5
3   13.0   23.0
4   14.0   24.0
4   14.3   24.3
4   14.6   24.6
4   14.9   24.9
5   15.0   25.0
5   15.5   25.5
1   16.0   26.0
2   17.0   27.0
3   18.0   28.0
4   19.0   29.0
4   19.4   29.4
4   19.8   29.8
5   20.0   30.0
EOD

set key out reverse Left noautotitle

myColors     = "0xff0000 0x00ff00 0x0000ff 0xff00ff"
myColor(col) = (t0=t1, t1=column(col), t1<t0 ? c=c+1 : 0, int(word(myColors,c)))
myTitles     = '"column2, 1st" "column2, 2nd" "column3, 1st" "column3, 2nd"'

plot t1=(c=1,NaN) $Data u 1:2:(myColor(1)) w p pt 7 lc rgb var, \
     t1=(c=3,NaN)    '' u 1:3:(myColor(1)) w p pt 7 lc rgb var, \
     for [i=1:4] keyentry w p pt 7 lc rgb int(word(myColors,i)) ti word(myTitles,i)
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Another trial. I don't know if your provided data is anywhere near to something realistic. If you plot such random data, why do you want to separate it into different curves even with the same color?

Anyway, here is a suggestion for interrupting a curve from continuous data (here additionally continuing with a different color).
The "trick" is to check whether the current value in column1 is smaller than the previous value. If this is the case, change the line color to transparent (e.g. `0xff123456`) otherwise loop between the 3 colors RGB (or take constant color).
The transparent line "trick" has the disadvantage that the first data point in a linespoints plot will miss its point (can be added separately if needed).

Another option would be to introduce an empty line after each sequence in column1 (from 1 to 5). But I assume you don't want to change your 200 MB data file.

Check the example below, but it could well be that I still haven't fully understood what you actually want.

**Script:**

```
### break data into several curves
reset session

$Data <<EOD
column1  column2  column3
  1         2        4
  1         3        6
  1         5        7
  1         9        0
  2         5        7
  2         8        9
  3         9        6
  4         4        3
  4         2        4 
  4         6        9
  4         0        0
  5         7        0 
  5         6        8
  1         5        2
  2         3        5
  3         6        7
  4         8        3
  4         2        1
  4         2        6
  5         8        9
  1         1        2   # some more data added for illustration
  2         3        8
  3         1        7
EOD

myColors     = "0xff0000 0x00ff00 0x0000ff"
myColor(col) = (t0=t1, t1=column(col), t1<t0 ? (c=c+1, 0xff123456) : int(word(myColors,c%3+1)))
set key noautotitle

plot t1=(c=0,NaN) $Data u 2:3:(myColor(1)) w lp pt 7 lc rgb var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, I try to be more precise.   1. your presumption is right;      2. I want to plot column2 versus  column3   using column1 as a ternary operator;         3. I had the same problem and thought that with points instead of lines would be easier to make (I would like to know how to do it with linepoints, if it isn't too much trouble, but not necessary);            4.  the column1 increases from 1 to 5 N times (it's a very big data >200Mb). Thanks for the patience.

Comment: @fae ok, please provide some reasonable complete minimal data. So column2 is x and steadily increasing and column3 is y. And in column1 a certain number can be repeated several times, but the next different number is always increased by 1, except for 5 it will be reset to 1, correct?

Comment: column2=x and column3=y, column1 repeats numbers form 1 to 5 (sometimes inbetween numbers can be missing), after a series of 5 it will alwasy come a 1.

Comment: @fae hmm, in other words you want to split your data (i.e. start a new line/linespoints curve) after the last 5 in a sequence (1 to 5). What is `N`? In your example it is `2`. What about the key/legend? If N is very large it doesn't make sense to have hundreds of key entries. What about the color, what colors do you want? And please, edit your question and add some complete minimized example data!

Comment: I edited the question to be more comprehensive.  I assume "N" would be at least 100.  The colour is not important and I don't need a key.

Comment: @fae thanks for the edit. If the x-values are not steadily increasing within a 1 to 5 set why do you want to plot with linespoints?  This will give some zig-zag back and forth, is this intended? So far, I only understand that you want to start a new curve after each completed `1 to 5` sequence (but no color change and no key entry), correct? I like finding solutions to tricky problems, but it seems the tricky problem is to find out what you really want ;-).

Comment: ahahah, I know I sound very confused (most probably I am). The code works perfectly thanks. And today I propose you another challange: what if I would have a column4 where sometimes the value is higher >0 (its not important how big the number, but just bigger than 0), and every time in column4 the number is higher than 0 I want that specific sequence from 1 to 5 to be dropped, and go to the next one. The outup shuold look like the same from above. Or if it easier to code that sequence to have another colour.

Comment: @fae ok, if this helped solving your problem, please upvote and accept, indicating that the question has been answered. For the new challenge, please start a new question (otherwise it will get too confused here) and add some reasonable test data which would result in a reasonable output. About skipping when column4 >0, this is probably a simple filter task (but also depends on the details, e.g. if one value in that sequence >0, skip the whole sequence?). So, please **exactly** describe what you have (structure of data format, etc.) and specify precisely what you want.